# Where are the context menu options defined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my own version of this open source chrome extension. It's called The Great Suspender. Following is the GitHub link.

https://github.com/deanoemcke/thegreatsuspender/tree/master/src

The context menu has options like "Never suspend this URL." I scanned through all the source but couldn't find that written anywhere. So, where on Earth are the labels for these context menus coming from?

Comment: Use a multi-file search in your IDE and you'll see it's inside messages.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context menu items are created by some Chrome API. Let's look at the API index: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

Aha, looks like [`chrome.contextMenus` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus). So let's scan the repository for that.

[image: Click for actual search]

We see code in the form of

```
title: chrome.i18n.getMessage('js_context_open_link_in_suspended_tab')
```

So, that's another API to look up, [chrome.i18n](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n). If you've never encountered that abbreviation before, it's short for ["internationalization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization), or enabling your program to be translated.

So, actual *strings* you're looking for are in the locale files as described by API docs, in `_locales` subfolder:

https://github.com/deanoemcke/thegreatsuspender/blob/master/src/_locales/en/messages.json

```
"js_context_never_suspend_page": { "message": "Never suspend this URL" },
```

That's what you are looking for. Those messages are pulled (in appropriate language, if supported, an in English as default) from `messages.json` in the locale folders.